# Getting random error "The client has disconnected" when there is high load on server and request body is big

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi

We are getting below error randomly when there high trafic to our server and as per our observation it seems that we are getting this error only for which has request body is big.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: The client has disconnected ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified network name is no longer available. (0x80070040)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IO.AsyncIOOperation.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadBody()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadAsync(Memory`1 memory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value, Object container)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

I have tried to read the request body in chunk , but this sollution didn't work.

Comment: Does this problem only occur on iis? and does it work properly locally? It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.